# What is wrong with this proof that the power set of the natural numbers is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here I offer a "proof" of why the power set of the natural numbers is countable by creating a supposed bijection. I know that my proof is wrong, but where? If anyone could point it out, that'd be awesome.

Consider the power set of the natural numbers. We can form a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ as follows.

For any $f(x)$ convert $x$ to its binary representation, which is a string of $0$s and $1$s. If the $i$-th digit is $1$, then include $i$ in the output set $S=f(x)$. Otherwise do not include $i$. Note that $i$ is $0$-indexed and starts from the right-most digit.

So in this case $f(5)=\{1,3\}$. Supposedly we can construct any set in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with an appropriate choice of $x$.

Where does this proof blow up?

Comment: Your construction does not give any infinite sets.

Comment: Yes, what $x$ has $f(x)=\mathbb N$? $\mathbb N\in P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: Interestingly, the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ *is* countable. I don't know if your $f$ is a bijection though.

Comment: @pjs36: Of course it is, and you can explicitly describe the inverse.

Comment: @user21820 Upon reflecting for a few hours, I concur: It *is* obvious :P

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you do give a bijection between the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, which is itself a proper subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Indeed the binary representation gives a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$, which take the value 1 only at finitely many numbers.

The usual bijection between the power set (= all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$) and the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ restricts exactly to a bijection between the set of finite subsets and the set of functions which vanish outside a finite subset.

Answer (score 0):

If f(x) is the set of i such that the i-th digit of x is i, then f(x) is a finite subset of N. No infinite subset of N is  equal to f(x) for any x. So f is not a surjection.